# Strategies for tracking down _objc_msgSend crashes inside dispatch_sync block

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch, crash-reports, hockeyapp

I'm receiving crash reports (via the excellent [Hockey](http://hockeyapp.net)) indicating that I've got a memory problem in some code that's called inside a `dispatch_sync` block (or at least that's how I'm interpreting the crash report snippet below). I've not been able to recreate this crash on my test devices at all (so strategies like `NSZombieEnabled` are not helping me). I'm happy to make code changes to make the crash reports more informative (and ultimately solve the underlying issue), I just don't know where to start. Any thoughts?

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0xb000000c
Crashed Thread:  7
...
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib            0x3979bb66 _objc_msgSend + 6
1   libdispatch.dylib          0x39c898fb _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 27
2   App                        0x00260f23 __48-[Foo displayLinkCallback]_block_invoke + 147
3   libdispatch.dylib          0x39c85103 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 11
4   libdispatch.dylib          0x39c894bf _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 111
5   libdispatch.dylib          0x39c8a7e5 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 225
6   libdispatch.dylib          0x39c8a9d1 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 57
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib    0x39db4dff __pthread_wqthread + 299
```

The `dispatch_sync` is provided a static serial queue. Is it possible that the `_objc_msgSend` is indicating a problem referencing this queue rather than some issue inside the block?

To pre-empt the obvious, I'm seeing no indication of deadlocks in these crash reports.

**Update (8th Oct '13)**

Adding code as requested (method and variable names changed, but still close to original). I suspect the issue is somewhere around the copying of `foo`. My hope was that this question would yield stategies for debugging this error. If 'check line by line' is the best strategy for debugging `_objc_msgSend` crashes inside `dispatch_sync` block then it's a little sad, but I'll take any help I can get at this point.

Also, I should point out that the crash I am investigating only ever happens on single-core devices and intermittently at that.

```
- (void) displayLinkCallback
{
    dispatch_async(_frameDispatchQueue, ^{
        if ([_lock tryLock])
        {
            dispatch_sync(_renderQueueSerial, ^{
                NSObject *fooCopy = nil;
                BOOL bar = NO;

                // prevents deallocation during subsequent copy
                // _foo is set and/or its child objects changed 
                // many times per second by other threads)
                NSObject *foo = _foo;

                // copy foo 
                fooCopy = [foo copy];

                bar = [self needsBarGivenFoo:fooCopy];
                if (bar)
                {
                    _lastFoo = foo;
                    [self goFoo:fooCopy];
                }
                else
                {
                    [self noFoo:fooCopy];
                }
            });
            [_lock unlock];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running Analyze under the Product menu? This runs static analysis and can help find memory errors and other issues.

Comment: @BergQuester yes. I have run the analyze tool over the project. No issues. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: It appears that this entire 'bug' was a red herring. When a seperate memory scribbling bug was resolved the issue mentioned on this page dried up too. Thank you to those who tried to help and to anyone experiencing anything like this in future, investigate [Xcode's Malloc Debugging features](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest starting your analysis on those references in your source files. This symbolicated crashlog suggests that your crash stems from something in the `displayLinkCallback` method in the `Foo` class. You should probably start your investigation there.

It's telling you had a segmentation violation. But it's hard to diagnose further without seeing the source code for that method.

Comment: Actually, that is not a symbolicated crash log. If it was it would show a filename and line number. This log only shows a method name and relative memory offset.

Comment: @rmaddy Quite right, that's not a line number. But it is symbolicated, though, isn't it, because you're seeing a method name rather than a raw crashlog with just memory addresses? If you look at an unsymbolicated crash log, you only have memory addresses.

Comment: You are correct. After a second look it appears to be symbolicated against a dSYM that didn't have any line number info, just a symbol table.

Comment: @Rob, @rmaddy this dSYM does indeed contain line numbers (reports for other crashes in this version point to files and line numbers). However this all breaks down once the issue occurs inside a dispatch, hence the question. Surely `0x00260f23` is just the address of the `_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke`?

Comment: @JaysenMarais In answer to your original question, I don't think that the queue, itself, is invalid, but probably the code in it (as when I `dispatch_sync` a block that crashes, I see something similar to your crashlog, but not identical, but if I use an invalid queue, it's very different). Making sense of the crash log might be easier if we could see the code.